# Swift - some mp3 file metadata return nil

Tags: swift, swift3, metadata, mp3, avplayer

I have code like below. For some file I got metadata like artist, title and other without any problem. For other files metadata list is nil but when I check metadata in editor like Tagger - title and other metadata exists. Furthermore when I change metadata in external editor for at least one key - my code starts work properly.

Could someone explain me where I make mistake ?

```
static func getBookInCatalog(url: URL) -> Book {

    let book = Book(url: url)
    let isDir: ObjCBool = false
    var directoryContents = [URL]()
    var totalTime: CMTime?
    var size: UInt64 = 0
    var chapters:Int = 0

    do {
        directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return book
    }

    for item in directoryContents {

        if !isDir.boolValue {

            let result = appDelegate.fileTypes.filter { $0==item.pathExtension.lowercased() }
            if !result.isEmpty {

                chapters += 1

                let fileSize = (try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: item.path)[FileAttributeKey.size] as! NSNumber).uint64Value
                size += fileSize

                let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: item)
                let metadataList = playerItem.asset.commonMetadata
                let asset = AVURLAsset(url: item, options: nil)
                let audioDuration = asset.duration

                if let _ = totalTime {
                    totalTime = totalTime! + audioDuration
                } else {
                    totalTime = audioDuration
                }

                for metadata in metadataList {

                    guard let key = metadata.commonKey, let value = metadata.value else{
                        continue
                    }

                    switch key {
                    case "albumName":
                        if book.title == nil || book.title == "" {
                            book.title = (value as? String)!
                        }
                    case "artist":
                        if book.author == nil || book.author == ""  {
                            book.author = (value as? String)!
                        }
                    case "artwork" where value is NSData:
                        if book.image == nil {
                            book.image = UIImage(data: (value as! NSData) as Data)
                        }
                    default:
                        continue
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    if let imageInsideCatalog = getImageFromFolder(url: url){
        book.image = imageInsideCatalog
    }

    if book.title == nil {
        book.title = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    }

    book.chapters = chapters
    book.totalTime = totalTime
    book.size = size


    return book
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MP3 meta data "standards" have gone through several major iterations over the years (see http://id3.org) . Your editor may be able to read older formats (that AVURLAsset may not support) and save them using the latest/current standard which would make them compatible after any change.